# Relative CSS urls in Webpack

Tags: webpack, css-loader, sass-loader

Webpack + file-loader + sass-loader is having trouble resolving relative paths for CSS background images.

The compiled SCSS file contains a path to the background image that is relative to `/dist/` instead of relative to the SCSS/CSS document. I researched this problem; sass-loader recommends using resolve-url-loader (with source maps). However, adding the resolve-url-loader made no difference to the compiled CSS.

I have been able to resolve the issue by setting the 'publicPath' to '../..' on the file-loader. Or by disabling the 'url' setting on the css-loader. Neither is a good solution and causes issues with copying files and referencing images via HTML or other sources.

The online examples of Webpack and CSS place the CSS and images in the same folder (often in the root). This is not an optimal choice for my webpack implementation. The concept of structuring files in subfolders seems like a fairly basic requirement. Is this simply the wrong approach?

Running Webpack ^3.5.1. Sass-loader ^6.0.6. File-loader ^0.11.2. Css-loader ^0.28.4.

**File structure**

```
example/
├── dist/
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── media
│   │   │   └── logo.png
│   │   └── styles
│   │       ├── app.css
│   │       └── app.css.map
│   ├── index.html
│   └── app.bundle.js
└── src/
    ├── assets
    │   ├── media
    │   │   └── logo.png
    │   └── styles
    │       └── app.scss
    └── app.js
```

**app.scss**

```
body {
  background: url(../media/logo.png);
}
```

**app.css**

```
body {
  background: url(assets/media/logo.png); //This should be ../media/logo.png
}
```

**app.js**

```
require('./assets/styles/app.scss');
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }, {
              loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
            }, {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      }, {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'assets/media/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/styles/app.css'
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ExtractTextPlugin` has a `publicPath` option that can resolve this issue.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/styles")
  ],
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    publicPath: '../../',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }, {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Added `include` array to target files in a particular directory. Recommended for instances where all stylesheets are located in the same folder.

Comment: In my case, `publicPath: './'` worked to resolve file path assets relative to the output directory.

Comment: As @James said, solution to this problem (in my case and I guess to others) was to add/edit output`s pablicPath option

Answer (score 3):

The reason why path in `url(...)` is incorrect is webpack generate path relative to output dir, not the output css file.

You can use [css-url-relative-plugin](https://github.com/yibn2008/css-url-relative-plugin) to solve this problem, it will replace `url(...)` with correct relative path by re-calculate relationship of output css and assets file.