# VueCLI + Static Assets + Directive

Tags: vuejs2, directive, vue-cli-3

I follow guide here: [Vue CLI - include image from assets folder in static file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531821/vue-cli-include-image-from-assets-folder-in-static-file#answer-52097176)

So in `assets` folder I have `img\pic.jpg`. I can call that image using normal html and css:

```
<img src="~@/assets/img/pic.jpg">

<style scoped>
.app {
  background: url(~@/assets/img/pic.jpg);
}
</style>
```

But for directive (correct me if the term if wrong), I tried this and of course failed. Can you help?

```
<img :src="'~@/assets/'+user.profilepic">

//Note:  user.profilepic = "img/pic.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${user.profilepic}`)" />
```

Comment: Why should the OP try it? Please, consider adding a dedscription of the proposed solution.

Comment: Thank you its working! Sadly I didn't quite understand. I have seen this kind of codes but confuse when to use. Will takes some times to get familiar